PyCharm GitLab Integration Plugin 'Cannot fetch any metadata for server:' (Self managed GitLab)
we use self hosted GitLab. So far everything works fine, I can clone the repositories and I can pull and push easily. Also the Task integration for Gitlab works very fine in PyCharm.
But as soon as I try to use the GitLab Integration Plugin (Settings -> Version Control -> GitLab) I receive the following error:

As I mentioned, PyCharm is able to clone and also use the Task integration. It just fails with the GitLab Integration Plugin.
I checked double and the scope of the access token is correctly set to api and read_user.
Furthermore I tried to delete all saved Passwords in the IDE and reconnect to my GitLab Account without success.
Also I would like to mention, that some of my colleagues could set up the GitLab Integration Plugin the same way I tried. Which leaves me in even bigger confusion.
